# How to create RxJava observables to collect smartphone data inside a service and be subscribed in an activity?

Tags: android, rx-java

### Context:

I'm trying to develop an Android application to gather data from many sources such as: battery, hardware, sensors, cell towers, satellites and wifis.

These data has to be "observed" inside a service because I need it to run in background in order to log the data and send it to my server. When the user opens the app I also need to show that data in the activity.

First I wrote my code using many `BehaviorSubject` singletons, each representing a data source. This way I could pass the data from service using the `onNext` method and subscribe to it anywhere. But now I want to get rid of `Subject` objects since it is recommended the usage of `Observable`.

---

### Problems:

I have two questions:

Question 1: How to create a RxJava `Observable` that registers a listener or a `BroadcastReceiver` at the first subscription and, when all subscribers call the `unsubscribe` method, it unregisters the listener or receiver?

I have this piece of code to listen to satellites:

```
private final GpsStatus.Listener gpsListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {

    GpsStatus gpsStatus = null;

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(gpsStatus);

        if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS) {
            if (gpsStatus != null) {
                //put satellite data in some list
            }
        }
    }
};

public registerSatellite() {
    locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsListener);
}

public void unregisterSatellite() {
    locationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(gpsListener);
}
```

I also have this piece of code to listen to battery information:

```
private BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //put intent data in some variable
    }
};

public registerBattery()
{
    context.registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

public unregisterBattery()
{
    context.unregisterReceiver(batteryReceiver);
}
```

Question 2: In order to pass data from service to activity, are singletons a good option?

Answer (score 1):

You could use RxJava's [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html). It emits all subsequent observed items to the subscriber and supports multiple subscribers:

```
PublishSubject<GpsStatus> subject = PublishSubject.create();
// observer1 will receive all onNext events
subject.subscribe(observer1);
subject.onNext(<GpsStatus#1>);
subject.onNext(<GpsStatus#2>);
// observer2 will only receive GpsStatus #3
subject.subscribe(observer2);
subject.onNext(<GpsStatus#3>);
```

In combination with a singleton, you could create a sort of Bus that allows generators (e.g. your `GpsListener`, `BroadcastReceiver`) to publish to activities.

Just don't forget to unsubscribe `onDestroy()`, otherwise you'll leak activities!